# Left join inside left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, left-join, sql-null

I have problem getting values from tables.

I need something like this

```
A.Id a1
  B.Id b1
     C.Id c1
  B.Id b2
     C.Id c2
     C.Id c3
     C.Id c4
```

Table A and B are joined together and also table B and C.
Table A can have one/zero or more values from table B. Same situation is for values from table C.

I need to perform left join on table A over table B and inside that left join on table B over table C.

I tried with left join from table A and B, but don't know how to perform left join inside that left join.

Is that possible? What would syntax for that look like?

edit:
Data would look like this

```
ZZN1  P1  NULL
ZZN1  P2  NAB1
ZZN2  P3  NAB2
ZZN2  P3  NAB3
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images. Take a look at [mcve] too.

Comment: Your description what what you "need" doesn't make sense. That looks like single row with indented values. If that *is* what you want that's for your presentation layer to do.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  It is unclear what columns are used for joining.  It is unclear whether you want rows from `C` when there is no match in `B` -- or even if that is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to nest the left joins, you can simply flatten them and let your RDMBS handle the logic.

Sample schema:

```
a(id)
b(id, aid) -- aid is a foreign key to a(id)
c(id, bid) -- bid is a foreign key to b(id)
```

Query:

```
select a.id, b.id, c.id
from a
left join b on b.aid = a.id
left join c on c.bid = b.id
```

If the first left join does not succeed, then the second one cannot be performed either, since joining column `b.id` will be `null`. On the other hand, if the first left join succeeds, then the second one may, or may not succeed, depending if the relevant `bid` is available in `c`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.Name, B.Name , C.Name 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
LEFT JOIN C ON B.id = C.id
```